# Need some hints about Resolution Rule prove

Tags: artificial-intelligence, logic, discrete-mathematics

It's a homework.  I'm trying to prove that **(a v b) ^(~b V c) |= (a V c)**

it's a correct resolution rule. And I'm not allowed to use resolution rule to prove it. 
Get little confusing, don't know what should I do at the first place..

And another problem, teacher let us to prove **KB |= a**, when **KB ^ ~a** is unsatisfiable. as far as I know , I may need to build a KB which includes several sentences, then I can prove 
**KB ^ ~a** is unsatisfiable. but teacher told to me If I want to derive an example, I have to let it suit for every cases.  I want to know is there an universal example to prove that? Do I have to use example?

Hope somebody can give me some hints or useful links.. Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with the rule you describe in the third paragraph:

First, build a knowledge base of everything you know: namely `a v b` and `~b v c`.

Then add the negation of the statement you're trying to prove: `~(a v c)`. You can rewrite this in CNF and add it to the KB.

Now show that this KB is unsatisfiable. There are two ways you can do this:

- Just make a truth table. There are eight possible assignments to `a`, `b`, `c`, so it'll have eight rows; you can show that at least one statement in the KB is false for any possible assignment. This isn't an "example", because you're considering all possible cases.
- Depending on the models you're using, you can make some inference within the KB itself. You'll have some statements that simply assert that a certain variable is true or false; you can then use that fact to simplify other statements in the KB. You'll want to check that you're doing this in a way that's appropriate in your formalism, though.

---

So, to prove that `KB ^ ~a` being unsatisfiable implies `KB |= a`, do a proof by contradiction:

- You have `KB`.
- Assume that, given `KB`, `~a` is satisfiable.
- But if that's true, then `KB ^ ~a` is satisfiable -- which you're proving is false, ie `KB ^ ~a` is unsatisfiable.
- Therefore our assumption must have been wrong, and so `~a` is unsatisfiable given `KB`.

Now you're pretty much there.

Comment: How about prove KB|=~a is unsatisfiable? is there any way that I do not use example to prove it?

Comment: @roccia Added details to my answer about how to do that.

Comment: I'v already proved the first one((a v b) ^(~b V c) |= (a V c) ) by using truth table. but still stuck on the second one. In your second parapraph(Depending on the models you're using,...), It seems I still have to build a KB, but how can I prove this KB is a general one that can represent any KB? And thanks for your help..

Comment: @roccia Oh, I didn't realize that you were also trying to prove that second statement -- I thought it was a suggested method for proving the first statement, which is what I was talking about in my answer. I've added some hints about proving that, too.

Comment: Thank you ver...y much , Although I've already figured out how to do that.